# One-To-Many relationship gets duplicate objects without using "distinct". Why?

Tags: java, hibernate, hql, distinct, one-to-many

I have 2 classes in a one-to-many relationship and a HQL query that is a bit strange. Even if I have read some questions already posted, it does not seem clear to me.

```
Class Department{
   @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy="department")
   Set<Employee> employees;
}
Class Employee{
   @ManyToOne
   @JoinColumn(name="id_department")
   Department department;
}
```

When I use the following query I get duplicates Department objects:

`session.createQuery("select dep from Department as dep left join dep.employees");`

Thus, I have to use distinct:

`session.createQuery("select distinct dep from Department as dep left join dep.employees");`

Is this behaviour an expected one? I consider this unusual, as comparing it with SQL.

Comment: why you make `left join`, just simple `from Department` also your fetch type is eager. What is the sql output?

Comment: acctually the query has a where clause, I need to put a condition for each employee and a `from Department` wont help me in this case. 


`select dep from Department as dep left join dep.employees emp where emp.enddate > current_date()`

Answer (score 98, accepted):

This question is thoroughly explained on [Hibernate FAQ](https://developer.jboss.org/docs/DOC-15782#jive_content_id_Hibernate_does_not_return_distinct_results_for_a_query_with_outer_join_fetching_enabled_for_a_collection_even_if_I_use_the_distinct_keyword):

> First, you need to understand SQL and how OUTER JOINs work in SQL. If
> you do not fully understand and comprehend outer joins in SQL, do not
> continue reading this FAQ item but consult a SQL manual or tutorial.
> Otherwise you will not understand the following explanation and you
> will complain about this behavior on the Hibernate forum.   Typical
> examples that might return duplicate references of the same Order
> object:

```
List result = session.createCriteria(Order.class)  
                        .setFetchMode("lineItems", FetchMode.JOIN)  
                        .list();

<class name="Order">           
    <set name="lineItems" fetch="join">
    ...
</class>

List result = session.createCriteria(Order.class)  
                        .list();
```

---

```
List result = session.createQuery("select o from Order o left join fetch o.lineItems").list();
```

> All of these examples produce the same SQL statement:

```
SELECT o.*, l.* from ORDER o LEFT OUTER JOIN LINE_ITEMS l ON o.ID = l.ORDER_ID
```

> Want to know why the duplicates are there? Look at the SQL
> resultset, Hibernate does not hide these duplicates on the left side
> of the outer joined result but returns all the duplicates of the
> driving table. If you have 5 orders in the database, and each order
> has 3 line items, the resultset will be 15 rows. The Java result list
> of these queries will have 15 elements, all of type Order. Only 5
> Order instances will be created by Hibernate, but duplicates of the
> SQL resultset are preserved as duplicate references to these 5
> instances. If you do not understand this last sentence, you need to
> read up on Java and the difference between an instance on the Java
> heap and a reference to such an instance.   (Why a left outer join? If
> you'd have an additional order with no line items, the result set
> would be 16 rows with NULL filling up the right side, where the line
> item data is for other order. You want orders even if they don't have
> line items, right? If not, use an inner join fetch in your HQL).
> Hibernate does not filter out these duplicate references by default.
> Some people (not you) actually want this. How can you filter them out?
> Like this:
>
> ```
> Collection result = new LinkedHashSet( session.create*(...).list() );
> ```
>
> A LinkedHashSet filteres out duplicate references (it's a set) and
> it preserves insertion order (order of elements in your result). That
> was too easy, so you can do it in many different and more difficult
> ways:

```
List result = session.createCriteria(Order.class)  
                        .setFetchMode("lineItems", FetchMode.JOIN)  
                        .setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY)  
                        .list();  

 
<class name="Order">  
    ...  
    <set name="lineItems" fetch="join">  
  
List result = session.createCriteria(Order.class)  
                        .setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY)  
                        .list();  
 
List result = session.createQuery("select o from Order o left join fetch o.lineItems")  
                      .setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY) // Yes, really!  
                      .list();  
 
List result = session.createQuery("select distinct o from Order o left join fetch o.lineItems").list();
```

> The last one is special. It looks like you are using the SQL
> DISTINCT keyword here. Of course, this is not SQL, this is HQL. This
> distinct is just a shortcut for the result transformer, in this case.
> Yes, in other cases an HQL distinct will translate straight into a SQL
> DISTINCT. Not in this case: you can not filter out duplicates at the
> SQL level, the very nature of a product/join forbids this - you want
> the duplicates or you don't get all the data you need.   All of this
> filtering of duplicates happens in-memory, when the resultset is
> marshalled into objects.   It should be also obvious why resultset
> row-based "limit" operations, such as setFirstResult(5) and
> setMaxResults(10)  do not work with these kind of eager fetch queries.
> If you limit the resultset to a certain number of rows, you cut off
> data randomly. One day Hibernate might be smart enough to know that if
> you call setFirstResult() or setMaxResults() it should not use a join,
> but a second SQL SELECT. Try it, your version of Hibernate might
> already be smart enough. If not, write two queries, one for limiting
> stuff, the other for eager fetching.   Do you want to know why the
> example with the Criteria query did not ignore the fetch="join"
> setting in the mapping but HQL didn't care? Read the next FAQ item.

Comment: I am having performance problems with this.  I am thinking maybe Hibernate is trying to create Java objects for each of the duplicated items and THEN doing a distinct?  So basically doing a lot of unnecessary object creation is causing a slow down, is this the case? Is there a more efficient solution?

Answer (score 0):

Use the result transformer `Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY`:

```
List result = session.createQuery("hql query")  
                        .setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY)  
                        .list();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
Query query = session.createQuery("queryStringWithEagerFetch").setHint(QueryHints.HINT_PASS_DISTINCT_THROUGH,false)
List result = query.list()
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Here's a great tip I learned about from Mr. Vlad Mihalcea. For more tips:
https://vladmihalcea.com/tutorials/hibernate/

```
    list = session.createQuery("SELECT DISTINCT c FROM Supplier c "
            +"LEFT JOIN FETCH c.salesList WHERE c.name LIKE :p1"
            , Supplier.class)
            .setHint(QueryHints.PASS_DISTINCT_THROUGH, false)
            .setParameter("p1", name + "%")
            .list();
```