# Spring Data JPA: What difference between findOne and findById?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, jpa

Unfortunately, i cannot find answer on my question. This question appears when i get incorrect data using method `findOne(ID id)`.

My project contains three entities each of them contains JPA **unidirectional** association `@OneToMany`.

> Example: Class A (contains List of Class B) -> Class B (contains List of Class C) -> Class C

Method `findOne(ID id)` return duplicates of Class B in List which relate to Class A. Unlike in the previous method, `findById(long id)` return correct number of related entities.
After some research I found out that `findOne(ID id)` use `Left Outer Join` in sql query.

I want to understand, there is the issue in `findOne(ID id)` method or it works properly.

Environment: Spring Data JPA 1.8.0.RELEASE, Hibernate 4.3.8.Final, MySQL

Comment: As outlined in the ticket you created [here](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJPA-709), the symptoms you see have nothing to do with `findOne(…)` at all. Whether associations return duplicate items solely depends on the persistence provider and your association mappings.

Comment: I've encountered the same issue. This answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/18753303/1407926 on an other post helped to understand what happend and why its happening. The consequence from that behaviour would be to use sets for one-to-many relationships and not lists right @OliverGierke?