# Result set whit duplicate rows in jpa (Hibernate)

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.1

I have the next sql query:

```
SELECT 
    @row_number:=@row_number+1 AS ID, IGN_DATES.PLACA, IGN_DATES.FECHA, OFF_DATES.FECHA
FROM
    (SELECT 
        a.PLACA AS PLACA, MIN(p.FECHA_GPS) AS FECHA
    FROM
        POSICIONHISTORIAL p
    JOIN AUTOMOVIL a ON p.SECAUTOMOVIL = a.SECAUTOMOVIL
    JOIN EVENTO e ON p.EVENTO_SECEVENTO = e.SECEVENTO
    WHERE
        p.FECHA_GPS BETWEEN '2016-09-01' AND '2016-10-01'
            AND e.CODIGO = 'ENC'
            AND a.PLACA IN ('SHS946', 'SHT011')
    GROUP BY a.PLACA , DAY(p.FECHA_GPS)) AS IGN_DATES
        JOIN
    (SELECT 
        a.PLACA AS PLACA,
            SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(p.FECHA_GPS
                ORDER BY p.FECHA_GPS DESC
                SEPARATOR ' , '), ',', 2) AS FECHA
    FROM
        POSICIONHISTORIAL p
    JOIN AUTOMOVIL a ON p.SECAUTOMOVIL = a.SECAUTOMOVIL
    JOIN EVENTO e ON p.EVENTO_SECEVENTO = e.SECEVENTO
    WHERE
        p.FECHA_GPS BETWEEN '2016-09-01' AND '2016-10-01'
            AND e.CODIGO = 'APA'
            AND a.PLACA IN ('SHS946', 'SHT011')
    GROUP BY a.PLACA , DAY(p.FECHA_GPS)) 
AS OFF_DATES ON DATE(IGN_DATES.FECHA) = DATE(OFF_DATES.FECHA),
(SELECT @row_number:=0) AS t;
```

I use mysql 5.7 and the result of this query is:

[Result Set in Mysql](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WweUM.png)

But the native query called from JPA 2.1 (Hibernate) return duplicate values of OFF_DATES.FECHA, this are the values from eclipse debug.

[Result set in JPA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q9AVb.png)

The rowid in the statement was aggregate with intent resolve the problem, but this was unsuccessful

Thanks for help me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [One-To-Many relationship gets duplicate objects whithout using "distinct".Why?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18753245/one-to-many-relationship-gets-duplicate-objects-whithout-using-distinct-why)

Comment: @AlanHay thanks for your comment, but not was useful for me, I posted my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this question, the problem is not the [One-To-Many relationship gets duplicate objects whithout using "distinct".Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18753245/one-to-many-relationship-gets-duplicate-objects-whithout-using-distinct-why).

The problem was the columns used for the join, I added one column more:

```
SELECT 
    @row_number:=@row_number+1 AS ID, IGN_DATES.PLACA, IGN_DATES.FECHA, OFF_DATES.FECHA
FROM
    (SELECT 
        a.PLACA AS PLACA, MIN(p.FECHA_GPS) AS FECHA
    FROM
        POSICIONHISTORIAL p
    JOIN AUTOMOVIL a ON p.SECAUTOMOVIL = a.SECAUTOMOVIL
    JOIN EVENTO e ON p.EVENTO_SECEVENTO = e.SECEVENTO
    WHERE
        p.FECHA_GPS BETWEEN '2016-09-01' AND '2016-10-01'
            AND e.CODIGO = 'ENC'
            AND a.PLACA IN ('SHS946', 'SHT011')
    GROUP BY a.PLACA , DAY(p.FECHA_GPS)) AS IGN_DATES
        JOIN
    (SELECT 
        a.PLACA AS PLACA,
            SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(p.FECHA_GPS
                ORDER BY p.FECHA_GPS DESC
                SEPARATOR ' , '), ',', 2) AS FECHA
    FROM
        POSICIONHISTORIAL p
    JOIN AUTOMOVIL a ON p.SECAUTOMOVIL = a.SECAUTOMOVIL
    JOIN EVENTO e ON p.EVENTO_SECEVENTO = e.SECEVENTO
    WHERE
        p.FECHA_GPS BETWEEN '2016-09-01' AND '2016-10-01'
            AND e.CODIGO = 'APA'
            AND a.PLACA IN ('SHS946', 'SHT011')
    GROUP BY a.PLACA , DAY(p.FECHA_GPS)) 
AS OFF_DATES ON DATE(IGN_DATES.FECHA) = DATE(OFF_DATES.FECHA)
AND IGN_DATES.PLACA = OFF_DATES.PLACA,
(SELECT @row_number:=0) AS t;
```